# Ubuntu is not booting (Windows Ubuntu Installer)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wubi

Its the first time I used the Windows Ubuntu Installer (WUBI).

I installed Ubuntu and everything went great, it then asked me to reboot my laptop and I kindly did , it went well, showed me the Optional boot up Windows 7 and Ubuntu in the Grub menu. But when I booted into Ubuntu it gave me only an underscore sign: _ and remains like this .

I haven`t tried to wait more then 20 minutes but I think this time should be enough for anything to show up

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Don't apologise, the only bad question is the one not asked ;) Check if any of the solutions here solve your problem: [Boot to black screen-Fixes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Thank you for the language check, i am reading in the help pages, still unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to BIOS > Security> I / O interface Security> "New Card Interface". Set it to Locked.

This Type of problem is cause from BIOS and usually in ASUS.